# Elegant way of evaluating 3d function on cube faces

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

I am trying to evaluate a 3d function F(x,y,z) on the six faces of a 3d-cube (all with the same mesh) and am looking for an elegant pythonic way of doing so. The order of evaluation doesn't matter. Currently I'm using collections to rotate lists, consisting of two grids and one constant, that represent the faces. But I somehow feel there must be a cleaner (and maybe faster?) way.

An example of my current way of doing so:

```
import collections
import numpy as np

def somefunc(x,y,z):
    return np.cos(x*y) + z

X,Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, -1:1:100j]
d1 = collections.deque([X,Y,1])
d2 = collections.deque([X,Y,-1])

for i in range(0,3):
    somefunc(*d1)
    somefunc(*d2)
    d1.rotate(1), d2.rotate(1)
```

I would find the most convenient way to be able to construct a grid or something similar of the cubes surface in one piece, so I would only have to call the function once. However, I can't find anything like that. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Looks pretty clean to me. Since a cube has always six faces you could avoid the loop altogether and call the function six times manually. :)

Comment: Well thank you! :) It's true I could call the function manually, but I was hoping there might be a smarter way to achieve this. Maybe something where I can loop over all six faces (not three and three as I do now).. but maybe there are not too many nice ways around that